# How to use SQL to implement logic similar to making change?

Tags: sql, function, sql-server-2008-r2, coin-change

The table Item has a field NUM_UNITS.

```
id      num_units
--      ---------
1       2
2       4
3       1
4       7
```

For the above rowset, sum(num_units) = (2 + 4 + 1 + 7) = 14.

I would like to write SQL code that allows me to change 14 to 14 - N (i.e. decrease), N being any number.

N = 3: row1: num_units=0, row3: num_units=0.

N = 4: row2: num_units=0

N = 5: row2: num_units=0, row3: num_units=0

N = 6: row2: num_units=0, row1: num_units=0, row3: num_units=0

N = 7: row2: num_units=0, row1: num_units=0, row3: num_units=0, **row4: num_units=6**

The goal is to effect the update such that SUM(NUM_UNITS) descreases by N rows.

Here's what I came up with so far: I made a function that tests the distance to the desired result when choosing N1 of the largest rows and N2 of the smallest rows.

```
ALTER FUNCTION F
(
    @GOAL INT,
    @P1 INT,
    @P2 INT
)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @X INT = (
        SELECT SUM(NUM_UNITS)
        FROM (
            SELECT TOP(@P1) ID, NUM_UNITS
            FROM ITEM
            ORDER BY NUM_UNITS DESC
            UNION
            SELECT TOP(@P2) ID, NUM_UNITS
            FROM ITEM
            ORDER BY NUM_UNITS ASC
        ) J
    )
    RETURN @GOAL - @X
END
GO
```

Now the trick is to call this successively, as well as find the next smallest row to remove the remainder from.

All that said, I'm interested in solving the problem, not in doing it this way in particular.  The logic reminds me of writing a program to make change.  I.e. if something costs X and the cashier receives Y, how does s/he go about choosing the bills and coins to give back optimally?

Any thoughts appreciated.  Suggestions on feasability and/or direction to go in are appreciated.  I could do this in another programming language but I'm trying to see if I can do it in SQL, partially as a learning experience.

Comment: I don't know if it's just me, but I don't understand what you're talking about, especially the "goal" - it's near unintelligible.

Comment: i'll try to clean it up, sorry

Comment: Agree @bohemian.  OP can you consider rephrasing the whole question?

Comment: @Gabriel - i reread and it makes sense to me, but maybe just focus on the goal instead of the function itself.

Comment: What version of SQL do you have?  I have a wiggling suspicion this can be done with a recursive CTE...

Comment: 2008r2.  I was also thinking recursion - just haven't been able to materialize it..

Comment: Do you want to reduce items to 0 until the sum has been reduced by N, or is it OK if we reduce some items only partially?

Comment: My goal is to (1) take the largest until the next largest would go over, then (2) take the smallest until the next smallest would go over, and reduce that last one by the remainder to get to 0. That said, I'd take a solution that spread it out if the end result was an N reduction in the sum(num_units) every time.  This is a case of a feature that has been lacking in my project forever - I have to do this manually every month :(

Comment: Isn't this a variation of [the famous bin packing problem](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/bin-packing-problems-the-sql/): "...is an NP-complete problem. It is a great way to make computer science students do some work and it is also useful in the real world. The basic problem statement is that you are given a set of (n) items. The items all have different volumes. We then have a supply of bins or boxes of the same size. The goal is to put the items into the bins and to minimizes the number of bins used..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Let N = 14**

**Here are the full contents of Table1 before the algorithm runs.**

[image]

**Here are the full contents of Table1 after the algorithm runs.**

[image]

This code is designed to run in one query window / SP.

**Declarations:**

```
declare @N int = 14
declare @Remaining int = @N
declare @CurrentID int
declare @Current_Num_Units int
```

**Step 1: Remove as many large records as possible**

```
Declare MaxCursor CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR
select id, num_units from Table1 order by num_units desc, id

-- Step 1: Remove as many large records as possible
OPEN MaxCursor
FETCH NEXT FROM MaxCursor
INTO @CurrentID, @Current_Num_Units

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

    if @Current_Num_Units <= @Remaining
    begin
        set @Remaining = @Remaining - @Current_Num_Units -- eliminate row and subtract from @Remaining
        update Table1 set num_units = 0 where ID = @CurrentID
    end
    else
    begin
        break -- exit loop if the this "next" record is too large to subtract from
    end

    -- grab the next record
    FETCH NEXT FROM MaxCursor
    INTO @CurrentID, @Current_Num_Units
END 

CLOSE MaxCursor
DEALLOCATE MaxCursor
```

**Step 2: Remove as many small records as possible**

```
-- Step2: Eliminate as many small records as possible
Declare MinCursor CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR
select id, num_units from Table1 where num_Units > 0 order by num_units, id  -- ascending instead of descending, j

Open MinCursor
FETCH NEXT FROM MinCursor
INTO @CurrentID, @Current_Num_Units

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

    if @Current_Num_Units <= @Remaining
    begin
        set @Remaining = @Remaining - @Current_Num_Units -- eliminate row and subtract from @Remaining
        update Table1 set num_units = 0 where ID = @CurrentID
    end
    else
    begin
        break -- exit loop if the this "next" record is too large to subtract from
    end

    -- grab the next record
    FETCH NEXT FROM MinCursor
    INTO @CurrentID, @Current_Num_Units
End

CLOSE MinCursor
DEALLOCATE MinCursor
```

**Step 3: Reduce the next available smallest record by the remainder**

```
-- Step 3. Take the next record and subtract the remaining difference from its num_units
set @CurrentID = (select top 1 ID from Table1 where num_units > 0 order by num_units, id)

update Table1 set num_units = num_units - @Remaining where ID = @CurrentID

-- Now we have reduced by N, starting with the high records, then the min records, then we took the difference out of a remaining record.
select * from table1
```

**Notes**

- This is not good SQL Code. SQL is best suited for set-based operations -- almost none of this is occurring. For a large dataset, you're almost certainly better suited doing this in a standard language like C# or VB.NET and saving the changes to the DB after.
- The looping above is handled with Cursors. Most of the time when somebody thinks they need a cursor to do something in SQL, they are doing something that is better suited to a standard coding environment as mentioned above.
- A few assumptions were made, such as some records always existing in the table, etc. I just wanted to lay down a framework that you can build off of.

Comment: Hi, thanks so much for your help..  I'll try this later today, I much appreciate it.